# Remove all images but first within a div

Tags: jquery, html

Take the following example

```
<div id="blog">
    <div class="postContent">
        <img src="img.png" alt="Keep this one"/>
        <img src="img.png" alt="REMOVE this one"/>
        <img src="img.png" alt="REMOVE this one"/>
        <img src="img.png" alt="REMOVE this one"/>
    </div>
    <div class="postContent">
        <img src="img.png" alt="Keep this one"/>
        <img src="img.png" alt="REMOVE this one"/>
        <img src="img.png" alt="REMOVE this one"/>
        <img src="img.png" alt="REMOVE this one"/>
    </div>
    <div class="postContent">
        <img src="img.png" alt="Keep this one"/>
        <img src="img.png" alt="REMOVE this one"/>
        <img src="img.png" alt="REMOVE this one"/>
        <img src="img.png" alt="REMOVE this one"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously I want to remove the images where the alt is (albeit different in production) "REMOVE this one"

What I have tried:

```
$('#blog .postContent img').slice(1).remove(); // AND
$('#blog .postContent img').not(':first').remove();
```

Result:

```
<div id="blog">
    <div class="postContent">
        <img src="img.png" alt="Keep this one"/>
    </div>
    <div class="postContent">
    </div>
    <div class="postContent">
    </div>
</div>
```

However my desired result is:

```
<div id="blog">
    <div class="postContent">
        <img src="img.png" alt="Keep this one"/>
    </div>
    <div class="postContent">
        <img src="img.png" alt="Keep this one"/>
    </div>
    <div class="postContent">
        <img src="img.png" alt="Keep this one"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm missing what I am sure should be very simple, will be very grateful for any pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `:not()` selector along with `:first-child` selector,

```
$('#blog .postContent img:not(:first-child)').remove();
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/w71c8kLk/)

Or you could use simple `css` for this purpose,

```
#blog .postContent img:not(:first-child){
  display:none;
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/w71c8kLk/1/)

Comment: Thank you, sadly I required a JS-only solution.

Comment: @Zanderwar You could pick anyone you want. By the way Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Pure CSS:**

```
.postContent img:nth-child(n+2) {
  display: none;
}
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/quf7kad1/)**

---

**jQuery Version:**

```
$('.postContent').each(function(){
$(this).children('img:nth-child(n+2)').remove();
});
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/quf7kad1/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

try this.use `first-of-type`

```
$('#blog .postContent img').not('img:first-of-type').remove()
```